# OpenVPN does not work on Wireless

Tags: vpn, openvpn

On some connections I have issues with OpenVPN accessing the internet and my internal network at home. I can do it at home but when I go to public wifi places I can't access my local network or even browse the web. The VPN connects perfectly fine to my server at home on my internal network.

Could it be that the wifi networks are overriding my DHCP and OpenVPN pushes from the server?

I have server and client 2.2 running

CONFIG:

```
##############################################
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file #
# for connecting to multi-client server.     #
#                                            #
# This configuration can be used by multiple #
# clients, however each client should have   #
# its own cert and key files.                #
#                                            #
# On Windows, you might want to rename this  #
# file so it has a .ovpn extension           #
##############################################

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote 72.4.49.4 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

# Verify server certificate by checking
# that the certicate has the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  This is an
# important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  The build-key-server
# script in the easy-rsa folder will do this.
#ns-cert-type server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
auth-user-pass
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
1fd6645f91c3a7f70549e8754e8bb5b
411361047787956cf76979f4572821c
551f04d42505f0a7434437c16d43972
fd074f2d2044fbca84e274edbcbe446
d09397b40cd025863e6bd7857b8658e
c60d14fe4212a7fd51d87ae847b3ff1
be2ab5d46cd46b721247b7579a2456c
d7ed5c0f17b96e024449b15892ccfdd
6b54b124471ef526becd464c6c5169c
a6667f7a4e988ae2a17569b46292709
42ead7a7824cdd12c88f3e9ddd032bd
169325478212090bb3243ff8f43e3c5
b886d265f618db002d7c599d270453a
bb09a4ec7f962dee0e541c7d4f0edcd
77d944ebd164748a3aff3ad02f1dec8
32ad9c0cd09b1a33ac1be790ae562e3
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
cipher AES-256-CBC

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20
```

### AT PUBLIC NETWORK

MY ROUTE when connected to the VPN:

```
192.168.5.x = local network at startbucks
192.168.2.x = my home local network
10.162.129.x = Open
72.4.49.4 = home ip

===========================================================================
Interface List
 25...00 ff 0c 42 83 bf ......TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
  4...18 3d a2 1a 1e 78 ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN
  3...b4 99 ba e2 86 52 ......Intel(R) 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
  9...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.5.1     192.168.5.78     25
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0     10.162.129.5     10.162.129.6     30
     10.162.129.1  255.255.255.255     10.162.129.5     10.162.129.6     30
     10.162.129.4  255.255.255.252         On-link      10.162.129.6    286
     10.162.129.6  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.162.129.6    286
     10.162.129.7  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.162.129.6    286
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0     10.162.129.5     10.162.129.6     30
     72.4.49.4  255.255.255.255      192.168.5.1     192.168.5.78     25
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0     10.162.129.5     10.162.129.6     30
      192.168.5.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.5.78    281
     192.168.5.78  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.5.78    281
    192.168.5.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.5.78    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.5.78    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.162.129.6    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.5.78    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.162.129.6    286
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  4    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 25    286 fe80::/64                On-link
  4    281 fe80::8c74:c5fb:4207:9f1f/128
                                    On-link
 25    286 fe80::98c9:2d2c:5e88:a0b6/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  4    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 25    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

ipconfig /all

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : StarBucks
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : sbx08514.tampafl.wayport.net

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-0C-42-83-BF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::98c9:2d2c:5e88:a0b6%25(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.162.129.6(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, January 31, 2014 8:46:59 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, January 31, 2015 8:46:59 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.162.129.5
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 419495692
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-41-7E-04-B4-99-BA-E2-86-52
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.10
                                       8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.10
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : sbx08514.tampafl.wayport.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6200 AGN
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 18-3D-A2-1A-1E-78
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8c74:c5fb:4207:9f1f%4(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.78(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, January 31, 2014 7:59:12 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, January 31, 2014 9:29:12 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 68697506
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-41-7E-04-B4-99-BA-E2-86-52
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.1
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : busines.network
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B4-99-BA-E2-86-52
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:8e:336c:bf79:2674(Preferred) 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8e:336c:bf79:2674%6(Preferred) 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234881024
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-41-7E-04-B4-99-BA-E2-86-52
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.sbx08514.tampafl.wayport.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : sbx08514.tampafl.wayport.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0C4283BF-8997-4AD9-BA99-944BEB2C0BCA}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

OpenVPN server config:

```
#################################################
# Sample OpenVPN 2.0 config file for            #
# multi-client server.                          #
#                                               #
# This file is for the server side              #
# of a many-clients <-> one-server              #
# OpenVPN configuration.                        #
#                                               #
# OpenVPN also supports                         #
# single-machine <-> single-machine             #
# configurations (See the Examples page         #
# on the web site for more info).               #
#                                               #
# This config should work on Windows            #
# or Linux/BSD systems.  Remember on            #
# Windows to quote pathnames and use            #
# double backslashes, e.g.:                     #
# "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\foo.key" #
#                                               #
# Comments are preceded with '#' or ';'         #
#################################################

# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port 1194

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
;dev-node MyTap

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca /etc/openvpn/internal.home.network/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/internal.home.network/keys/issued/internal.home.network.crt
key /etc/openvpn/internal.home.network/keys/private/internal.home.network.key

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh1024.pem 1024
# Substitute 2048 for 1024 if you are using
# 2048 bit keys.
dh /etc/openvpn/internal.home.network/keys/dh.pem


username-as-common-name
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login
client-cert-not-required

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.162.129.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/lib/openvpn/internal.home.network-ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
;client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
;duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/internal.home.network/keys/ta.key 0

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
;cipher BF-CBC        # Blowfish (default)
;cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
;cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
;max-clients 100

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
user nobody
group nogroup

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status /var/log/openvpn/internal.home.network-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn/internal.home.network.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20
# Use a secure cryptographic cipher.
cipher AES-256-CBC

# Revoked certificate list
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/internal.home.network/keys/crl.pem

# Advanced clients configurations
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/internal.home.network/configs
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"; Allow access to local network.
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.2.10"
push "dhcp-option WINS 192.168.2.10"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

OpenVPN server routes:

```
root@openvpn:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.162.129.0    10.162.129.2    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.162.129.2    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**How do I add a gateway/route so that mine trumps the starbucks one?**

Comment: Post the results of `route` and `ifconfig` when connected to VPN from home, and if possible, on the public wireless.

Comment: Could you please post logs from some of the unsuccessful attempts?

Comment: The VPN connects fine as stated above. I just can't browse the internet or ping outside IPs or IPs on my home network.

Comment: `0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.5.1     192.168.5.78     25`
`0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0     10.162.129.5     10.162.129.6     30`  The starbucks GW will win every time, lower metric, larger netmask..

Answer (score 1):

Your VPN server has this option `push "redirect-gateway def1"`.  This means the openvpn server is not pushing a 'default' gateway, which is generally understood to mean a route for the network range defined by `0.0.0.0/0`.

Using that option means your VPN server will send two routes `0.0.0.0/1`, and `128.0.0.0/1` (or 0.0.0.0/128.0.0.0 and 128.0.0.0/128.0.0.0 if you like the masks expanded).  Since routes are processed from most specific to least specific, this means that these two routes should take precedence over any routes for `0.0.0.0/0`.

You also have `bypass-dhcp` option to `redirect-gateway` set.  This will add static routes for the DHCP server your client used.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this statement

```
 redirect-gateway def1
```

to your client configuration file.